# Sqlite PDO query returns no results

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

**Getting no results no matter how broad my query**
PHP: 5.3
Sqlite3: 3.6
PDO: 5.3.3
I would think this should be a very simple process but even looking around I still don't know why I'm getting 0 results. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$sqlite = new PDO('sqlite:/example.db');
$result = $sqlite->query('SELECT * from  foo');
if(!$result)
{
    echo 'fail';
    return false;
}
?>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? The 'foo' table will only have four columns, and this test db only has one table. Running the query in sqlite displays the results fine.

Comment: you get an `exception`? Also how do you fetch the details from `$result`

Comment: No exception. I'm not fetching yet the variable is empty, doesn't matter?

Comment: Ok, are you sure the Data is in ? if no exception, table should be there anad available thru ur PHP. The insert operation might not be commited in you other sqllite session?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the insert operation. I can run this from command line and get all 7 rows returned: sqlite example.db 'SELECT * from foo'

Comment: to get exceptions run: `$sqlite->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Wow thanks - **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 26 file is encrypted or is not a database' in test.php:9 Stack trace: #0 test.php(9): PDO->query('SELECT * from foo') #1 {main} thrown in test.php on line 9**

Comment: I wonder why though if I can run that sqlite query on it from command line..

Comment: Check if `php` has read/write access to the sql database file?

Comment: Yep, we're all fixed up. Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to execute the statement first than fetch the result.

You might add try/catch block around the execute method call. and do some error handling.

Here's an example of catching an Exception. Do not use it as a design guideline.

```
<?php

try
{
    $sqlite = new PDO('sqlite:/example.db');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$statement = $sqlite->prepare('SELECT * from  foo');
try
{
     $statement->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
     echo "Statement failed: " . $e->getMessage();
     return false;
}

$result = $statement->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: Actually I believe whether you fetch the result or not, the var should be true for data. I do have it in try catch, and fetch follows the test to see if !$result. The problem turned out to be a rights issue, discovered by catching the exception. Therefore the var was still empty. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give a better guidance for debugging. I'm now here. :)